# XML Save to file Javascript asp

Tags: javascript, xml, asp-classic, rss

I need help writing and saving to a xml file. I am trying to use the code below. If anybody can help would be great. This code below loads the XML file and displays it on a page. Anybody know how i can save to it?  Many thanks.

We are building a project based on classic ASP.

```
<%@language=JScript%>

<%
   var objSrvHTTP;
   objSrvHTTP = Server.CreateObject ("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0");
   objSrvHTTP.open ("GET","http://www.hiddenurl.com/rss.xml", false);
   objSrvHTTP.send ();
   Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
   Response.Write (objSrvHTTP.responseXML.xml);
%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write the XML to the file system, you could so this:

```
<%
var objSrvHTTP;
objSrvHTTP = Server.CreateObject ("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0");
objSrvHTTP.open ("GET","http://www.hiddenurl.com/rss.xml", false);
objSrvHTTP.send ();

var fs,tfile;
fs=new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
tfile=fs.CreateTextFile(Server.MapPath("/somefile.xml"));
tfile.Write(objSrvHTTP.responseXML.xml);
tfile.Close();
%>
```

Comment: I am getting errors. 

Description: Permission denied
Error Category: Microsoft JScript runtime on tfile=fs.CreateTextFile

Comment: I figured it out. Was server permissions. Your code worked. Thanks!